# How to style the immediate child of multi level list?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a multi-level ul list like below.

> ```
> <ul>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="/"></a>
>             </li>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="/">
>                 </a>
>                 <ul>
>                     <li>
>                         <a href="/"></a>
>
>                         <ul>
>                             <li>
>                                 <a href="/"></a>
>                             </li>
>                             <li>
>                                 <a href="/"></a>
>
>                                 <ul>
>                                     <li>
>                                         <a href="/"></a>
>                                     </li>
>                                     <li>
>                                         <a href="/"></a>
>                                     </li>
>                                 </ul>
>                             </li>
>
>                         </ul>
>                     </li>
>                     <li>
>                         <a href="/"></a>
>                     </li>
>             </li>
>             </li>
>         </ul>
> ```

There could be more levels inserted.

So I want every ul > li > a will have a padding-left+10 of it's parent a tag.

Comment: you just answered your own question `ul > li > a { /*styles */} `

Answer (score 0):

you can use forloop for adding css for all the anchor tags at once.
add class in anchor tag for get element by class

var lis = document.getElementByClass("link").getElementsByTagName("li");

after this you can implement css using javascript:

var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule('a { padding-left: 50px; }', sheet.cssRules.length);

Comment: Why would you resort to use JS when it could be easily achieved by CSS?